# c# datetimepicker set time

Tags: c#, time, set, datetimepicker

On my WinForm, I want a user to be able to 'reset' or 'clear' the datetimepicker on a buttonclick. My goal is to set it to 00:00 AM, but am unable to do so.

I've tried:

`dateTimePicker1.Value = ("00:00: AM");`

```
int reset = int.Parse("00:00: AM");

dateTimePicker1.Value = reset;
```

The datetimepicker is in a custom format: `hh:mm:tt`

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing your custom format from `hh:mm tt` to `HH:mm tt`.

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "HH:mm tt";
dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

As we can see at MSDN
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=VS.110,d=hv.2%29.aspx:
"hh" - The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 01 to 12.
"HH" - The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 00 to 23.

So, we can expect the following behavior:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2015, 02, 19, 0, 0, 0);
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays 12:00 AM
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("HH:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays 00:00 AM
```

Comment: i was looking for these
"hh" - The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 01 to 12.
"HH" - The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 00 to 23.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

Doing that, hours, minutes and seconds will be set to 00:00:00.

Comment: This doesn't completely solve my issue, as it shows as 12:00 AM due to my custom format. I need a solution that overrides that to display `00:00 AM`

Answer (score 2):

type of dateTimePicker1.Value is DateTime. So try something like this:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now.Date;
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "HH:mm tt";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

This will work fine.

Comment: This doesn't completely solve my issue, as it shows as 12:00 AM due to my custom format. I need a solution that overrides that to display `00:00 AM`